# How to Deploy Kubernetes yaml using C#

Tags: c#, kubernetes, .net-core

I have yaml file

```
  apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
   kind: CronJob
   metadata:
     name: ct-cron
   spec:
     schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
     concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
     jobTemplate:
       spec:
         template:
           metadata:
             labels:
               app: your-periodic-batch-job
               aadpodidbinding: managedaks
           spec:
             containers:
             - name: redmine-cron
               image: orm.azurecr.io/py-app:v3
               imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
             - name: redmine-cron1
               image: orm.azurecr.io/py-app:v5
               imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
               volumeMounts:
                 - name: store01-inline1
                   mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
                   readOnly: true            
             restartPolicy: OnFailure
             volumes:
               - name: store01-inline1
                 csi:
                   driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
                   readOnly: true
                   volumeAttributes:
                     secretProviderClass: "azure-kvname-podid"
```

I stored this yaml as a string in the database.I want to deploy this YAML using c# code. But I couldn't find any option to deploy the yaml file using c# code.Is it possible ?

Comment: You need to use k8s C# sdk for this https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with the nuget package *KubernetesClient*

it includes a yaml parser, [sample](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/blob/master/examples/yaml/Program.cs)

```
var typeMap = new Dictionary<String, Type>();
typeMap.Add("v1/Pod", typeof(V1Pod));
typeMap.Add("v1/Service", typeof(V1Service));
typeMap.Add("apps/v1beta1/Deployment", typeof(Appsv1beta1Deployment));

var objects = await Yaml.LoadAllFromFileAsync(args[0], typeMap);
```

Those objects can be applied with the Kubernetes class' *Create* methods e.g. Namespace

```
var k8SClientConfig = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile();
IKubernetes client = new Kubernetes(k8SClientConfig);

var ns = new V1Namespace { Metadata = new V1ObjectMeta { Name = "test" } };
var result = client.CreateNamespace(ns);
```

Comment: How to apply `objects` to `ns`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the KubernetesClient c# sdk as others have pointed. Here is an example to create a namespace. Cronjob is in BatchV1Api class, so while deserializing your yaml, use that.

```
using k8s;
using k8s.Models;

public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        KubernetesClientConfiguration config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildDefaultConfig();
        IKubernetes client = new Kubernetes(config);

        var label = "label name";
        var nsContent = $@"apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    label1 : {label}";
        var objs = KubernetesYaml.LoadAllFromString(nsContent);
        var ns = (V1Namespace)objs[0];
        await client.CoreV1.CreateNamespaceAsync(ns);

        // Or you can use the Deserialize method as follows
        var nsContent2 = $@"apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: test2
  labels:
    label1 : {label}";
        var ns2 = KubernetesYaml.Deserialize<V1Namespace>(nsContent2);
        await client.CoreV1.CreateNamespaceAsync(ns2);
    }
}
```