# Can I create custom resources in Kubernetes without writing classes from them in C#?

Tags: c#, azure, kubernetes

I'm using custom resources installed from https://azure.github.io/azure-service-operator/. I'm creating them currently in a yaml file and then using `kubectl apply`. I have an AKS cluster that I would like to use the c# client to do the same thing.

1. Is there a way to use kubectl apply through the C# kubernetes client?
2. If not, is there a way to apply the yaml without having to create classes or a client set defining the custom resources in C#?

Answer (score 0):

> If not, is there a way to apply the YAML without having to create classes or a client set defining the custom resources in C#?

Yes, you can use the CSharp **Kubernetes** client to apply **YAML** files without having to create classes or a client set defining the custom resources.

- You can use the `kubectl` command-line tool to apply the YAML file, and use it in the CSharp of Kubernetes client to fetch the status of the custom resource.

> I followed this [blog](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_create_secret_generic/) for creating Kubernetes secrets. Creating secrets in Kubernetes using the `kubectl create secret` command.
>
> ```
> kubectl create secret generic my-secret --from-literal=username=myuser --from-literal=password=****
> ```

```
var config = new KubernetesClientConfiguration { Host = "https://kubernetes.default.svc", ClientCertificateData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(certFile), ClientKeyData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(keyFile), };

KubernetesClientConfiguration config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildDefaultConfig();
IKubernetes client = new Kubernetes(config);

var client = new Kubernetes(config);
var label = "Mylabel";
var nsCont = $@"apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
 name: test
 labels:
   label1 : {label}";
var obj = KubernetesYaml.LoadAllFromString(nsCont);
var ns = (V1Namespace)obj[0];
await client.CoreV1.CreateNamespaceAsync(ns);

var nsCont2 = $@"apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
 name: test2
 labels:
   label1 : {label}";
var ns2 = KubernetesYaml.Deserialize<V1Namespace>(nsCont2);
await client.CoreV1.CreateNamespaceAsync(ns2);
```

[image]

References: [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63229166/how-to-deploy-kubernetes-yaml-using-c-sharp) by `leaner12`.